# Custom width and height of a custom view-Android

Tags: android

Lets say I have an irregular shape in png format.As you know this shape considered in an *invisible square or rectangular* when I defined a view (its background is sourced from this png) on my xml.On my activity,I write a piece of code which sends an alertdialog when clicked on the view.even if I click a place which has no revelant with the shape (but it is in that invisible area)I get the dialog.I want to get an action when I click ONLY shape.How can I solve ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically,

1. You have to find a way to correctly and efficiently model the surfaces in the PNG file.
2. Then you can implement `onTouch(MotionEvent event)` of your view to handle the motion events and match the coordinates of the touch with your implementation in the first step.

---

Comment: With lots of researches,I found somethings.I can get the touchEvent coordinates now and I check that these coordinates are on my view or not.Thanks for answer..